# How to implement zooming in GDI-drawn MFC's CScrollView

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi

I'm drawing some graphics and text with GDI in my CScrollView. I need to implement the zooming functionality. I only need the zoom **out** functionality, no need to zoom **in** more than what is normally rendered.

Here are my best ideas:

1. Use MM_ANISOTROPIC mapping mode with SetWindowExt/SetViewportExt... The problem with this approach is that it does not scale text. Is there any way to force MFC to scale the text as well? Only thing I can think of is to set text font size according to the selected zoom value, but I'm not sure whether this will look well after all...
2. Draw to memory DC, and use StretchBlt to blit to the client area of appropriate size (set with SetScrollSizes...). This will solve the text scaling issue.

Also it is desirable to have antialiasing effect in the process. I think both methods above should accomplish this per se, but I don't know which will look better. Also I will have to implement printing/print-preview functionality later (using MFC's standard implementation from doc/view architecture), so I need the method to be compatible with that.

Need your advice please. Which way to go and why. Maybe other options exist too?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the second method I proposed in the question, but used DIBs instead of DDBs (and `StretchDIBits()` instead of `StretchBlt()`) because it proved to cause less problems, especially when using big bitmaps, and when printing.

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to mess with the mapping mode when you use MFC -- MFC itself already uses it for (at least) the print preview functionality.

I'd see if [`SetWorldTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145104.aspx) will work for you. At least with vector/TrueType fonts, it will scale the text along with everything else. Note that before `SetWorldTransform` will work, you need to call [`SetGraphicsMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162977.aspx) with `GM_ADVANCED`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Jerry. Unfortunately the method you mentioned has two problems: It does not scale text (drawn using DrawText API), and it does not have anti-aliasing effect (probably because it performs logical transformation of coordinates and sizes but e.g. LineTo function still draws the jagged lines). So this leaves me with second method I described above (drawing to mem dc and then StretchBlt) - what do you think about it? Can you recommend it?..